# Azure DevOps: Escape content of Variable

Tags: azure-devops

I have the following task which should write the content of `VAR` to a file.

```
  - task: Bash@3
    displayName: Nemo
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: |
        echo $(VAR) >> 'conf.json'
```

The problem is, that `VAR` contains JSON content and so I alway get the error:

> ```
> line 1: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
> ```

How can I escape the content of  `VAR`?

Comment: Would you please let me know how did you define your variable? Did you define it yourself or get it from other steps? Would you please share a sample of your variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just simply copy and paste my sample, hope this can help

```
parameters:
- name: listOfValues
  type: object
  default:
    this_is:
      a_complex: object
      with:
        - one
        - two

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- task: Bash@3
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      echo $VAR >> conf.json
  env:
    VAR: ${{ convertToJson(parameters.listOfValues) }}


- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: inline
    script: |
      Get-Content -Path ./conf.json
```

variables should be a json string and you can also convert it from object parameters like me.

above code works at my side:

[image]